# Ionic missing InAppBrowser plugin error When doing custom authentication

Tags: ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I've created an Ionic app and I'm trying to use the [Custom Authentication option](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/custom-authentication) eg. `Ionic.Auth.login('custom', authOptions, data).then(success, failure);` However, I get an error message in the failure saying "*Missing InAppBrowser plugin*".
The plugin is installed and I've tried to uninstall and reinstall the plugin with no luck. When I use 'basic' the request goes through fine.

How do I fix this or get around it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plugins only work when running in native devices. You can't use them on browser with `ionic serve`.

You may want to start testing on a real android device or emulator.

Alternatively, there's a [chrome plugin called Ripple](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc) that emulate an real devices with native-like features, allowing you to use some plugins on browser.

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually using Ripple :( I'll try on a mobile device

Comment: Works on my phone however does not work on Ripple. Is there any way I can get it to work with Ripple, or with the above method through `ionic serve`?